# How to convert auditD logs to json format efficiently using rsyslog modules

Tags: linux, logging, audit, rsyslog

I need to convert default audit daemon logs into JSON formatted logs using rsyslog. The Audit daemon has multiple Audit Record Types for every Audit Event Field. Creating rules for each Record Type is not efficient.

Are there any modules or methods for this? I've already tried using `rulebase.rb` and `mmpstructdata`.

Current logs:

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1576848185.440:407340): user pid=22571 
    uid=0 auid=1000 ses=3 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="root" 
    exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=pts/0 
    res=success'

type=CWD msg=audit(1364481363.243:24287):  cwd="/home/shadowman"

type=PATH msg=audit(1364481363.243:24287): item=0 
    name="/etc/ssh/sshd_config" inode=409248 dev=fd:00 
    mode=0100600 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 
    obj=system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0  objtype=NORMAL cap_fp=none 
    cap_fi=none cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
```

Expected format:

```
{
  "type": "USER_AUTH",
  "time_stamp": 1576848185.44,
  "msg_id": 407340,
  "pid": "22571",
  "uid": 0,
  "auid": 1000,
  "ses": 3,
  "msg": {
    "op": "PAM:authentication",
    "acct": "root",
    "exe": "/usr/bin/sudo",
    "hostname": "?",
    "addr": "?",
    "terminal": "pts/0",
    "res": "success"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking questions, please provide examples of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your logs is that they are inconsistent. This means that if you want to use rsyslog, you'll have to create a template and/or ruleset, depending on the how the logs deviate from the *standard* format.

You can use the [mmjsonparse](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules/mmjsonparse.html) module as well as [templates](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/templates.html) with constant and variable statements to parse the input message and generate the desired JSON output.

For the following *standard* messages:

```
type=CWD msg=audit(1364481363.243:24287):  cwd="/home/shadowman"

type=PATH msg=audit(1364481363.243:24287): item=0 
    name="/etc/ssh/sshd_config" inode=409248 dev=fd:00 mode=0100600 
    ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0  
    objtype=NORMAL cap_fp=none cap_fi=none cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
```

... this can be done by using a standard JSON template and the `mmjsonparse` function.

```
module(load="mmjsonparse")

if $programname == 'auditd' then {
  if $msg contains 'CWD' then {
    action(type="mmjsonparse"
           rule="defaultRule"
           name="parseCwd")
    action(type="omfile"
           file="/path/to/output/cwd.json"
           template="CwdJSONFormat")
  }
  if $msg contains 'PATH' then {
    action(type="mmjsonparse"
           rule="defaultRule"
           name="parsePath")
    action(type="omfile"
           file="/path/to/output/path.json"
           template="PathJSONFormat")
  }
}

template(name="PathJSONFormat"
         type="list") {
  constant(value="{")
  property(name="timegenerated"
           dateFormat="rfc3339")
  constant(value=",")
  property(name="hostname")
  constant(value=",")
  property(name="syslogtag")
  constant(value=",")
  property(name="procid")
  constant(value=",")
  property(name="msg"
           format="json")
  constant(value="}")
}

ruleset(name="defaultRule") {
  action(type="mmjsonparse"
         parseType="keyvalue"
         key=".msg")
}
```

The template for the `cwd` logs will look the same - just with less properties.

However, this can **not** be applied exactly the same way to the following message (`msg`):

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1576848185.440:407340): user pid=22571 uid=0 
    auid=1000 ses=3 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="root" 
    exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
```

... as it also contains a `msg` key-value pair. This means the keys of `msg.msg` have to be specifically paired with each value. The following conditional, template and ruleset can be appended to the config above.

```
if $programname == 'auditd' then {
  if $msg contains 'USER_AUTH' then {
    action(type="mmjsonparse"
        rule="userAuthRule"
        name="parseUserAuth")
    action(type="omfile"
        file="/path/to/output/user_auth.json"
        template="UserAuthJSONFormat")
}

template(name="UserAuthJSONFormat"
         type="list") {
  constant(value="{")
  property(name="timegenerated"
           dateFormat="rfc3339")
  constant(value=",")
  property(name=".msg.type"
           format="json")
  constant(value=",")
  property(name=".msg.time_stamp"
           format="json")
  constant(value=",")
  
  # ... all other properties (msg_id, pid ...)

  property(name=".msg.msg"
           format="json")
  constant(value="}")
}

ruleset(name="userAuthRule") {
  action(type="mmjsonparse"
         parseType="keyvalue"
         key=".msg.type")
  action(type="mmjsonparse"
         parseType="keyvalue"
         key=".msg.time_stamp")
  
  # ... action for each keyvalue to be paired (msg_id, pid ...)

  action(type="mmjsonparse"
         parseType="keyvalue"
         key=".msg.msg")
}
```

---

**Note:** These templates and ruleset do **not** contain all properties as described in the message. They are examples of what the templates or rulesets should look like.

This answer was also made based on the assumption, that the rest of the rsyslog configuration *(which is not included in the question)* is working.

Comment: Hi, is there any parameter called parseType/key available for mmjsonparse module?

Comment: I was unable to find documentation on the `parseType` action parameter. As far as I know, no. Atleast I've never seen it before.

Comment: Why would you need a "key only" parseType?

Comment: I won't get your question but.  I have a requirement to convert audit log data into structured JSON data. I looked for some answers but I didn't get them. I saw some possibilities in mmaudit module, field separation, and mmjsonparse but won't work until now

Comment: mmpstrucdata won't parse the message it simply stores it under `$msg` property even if I gave an rfc5424 log using logger "logger "rfc5424 message".  I don't know how to compile mmaudit

Comment: The answer I posted should work for the logs you provided. If you have questions about the module `mmpstrucdata` for parsing data in `RFC5424` format, feel free to ask a new question here on Stack Overflow. If you have a question about how to compile the `mmaudit` module, it's probably best off on [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) as it is more on-topic over there and the number of experts on this topic is probably higher.